# How to find the queue of CSV to export?

Tags: magento2, cron, export, message-queue

I'm running a Magento 2 Commerce and trying to export it via admin panel it didn't work, it seems like it's running forever in the background.

[image: Magento 2 Commerce Export issues]

How could I check the export queue and clean it?

Is it in my database or files in the var folder?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure cron job is running - https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/system/data-export.html

> Upon completion of the task, the file is processed through a message queue (**make sure your cron job is running**). The exported file is saved in the var/export/ folder

Make sure env.php has `cron_consumers_runner` configuration as mentioned in this [documentation.](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/mq/manage-message-queues.html)

If we want to run manually, please follow the below instructions.

To view a list of all consumers:

```
bin/magento queue:consumers:list
```

To run specific consumer.

```
bin/magento queue:consumers:start <consumer_name>
```

Example to run export consumer

```
php bin/magento queue:consumers:start exportProcessor
```

A successful run looks like this.

[image]

**Related tables**

[image: Related tables]